# How to display progressDialog in Android?

Tags: android, progressdialog, dismiss

i want to display progressDialog in my activity when im call webservices and call to webservices ends Dialog dismiss automatically can any know how to do this and i want some sample for it .
Thankx in advance .

here is my code but it not working fine

```
final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(
                RouteServicing.this, "", "Loading. Please wait...", true);

        final Handler handler = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        };

        Thread checkUpdate = new Thread() {
            public void run() {

                Status = cn.callWebService(url);
                getDetail(Status);
                //handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        };
        checkUpdate.start();
```

it shows me this error

```
    02-02 16:06:53.219: E/WindowManager(1127): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.palewar.coinop.RouteServicing has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@405db660 that was originally added here
02-02 16:06:53.219: E/WindowManager(1127):  at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:272)
02-02 16:06:53.219: E/WindowManager(1127):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
02-02 16:06:53.219: E/WindowManager(1127):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
02-02 16:06:53.219: E/WindowManager(1127):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
02-02 16:06:53.219: E/WindowManager(1127):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
02-02 16:06:53.219: E/WindowManager(1127):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:107)
02-02 16:06:53.219: E/WindowManager(1127):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:90)
02-02 16:06:53.219: E/WindowManager(1127):  at com.palewar.coinop.RouteServicing.onClick(RouteServicing.java:243)
```

Comment: What isn't working? more information about specifics dont be so vague.

Answer (score 1):

change method to:

```
Thread checkUpdate = new Thread() {
            public void run() {

                Status = cn.callWebService(url);
                getDetail(Status);
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            }
        };
```

Comment: Can plz tell me what i need to change in the above method .